# How do I use the %group feature in Theos / Logos?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, sdk, cydia

I have heard that there is a %group feature in theos. From what I have understood about this I guess it is for applying lots of hooks if a condition is set true or when you want to easily enable or disable it instead of using if(). Is what I am saying true? And how can I use this feature if a condition is met? Please help me as I really need this feature as i have lots of ifs and else in my code and it would be a lot easier to just use %group instead of all that! Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer;

1. You can use `%group thegroupname` before a `%hook` but remember to put two `%end`'s after.
2. In your `%ctor` you can call `%init(thegroupname);` when needed.

Hope this helps someone! Btw, the `%init()` function can be used anywhere, even inside `%hook`.

```
%group MessagesApp

%hook CLASS_TO_HOOK

- (id)FUNC_TO_HOOK {
    return %orig;
}

%end

%end //Don't forget your second end.

%ctor {
    if (TRUE) {
        %init(MessagesApp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also note that you can indent your `%hooks`'s inside the group to make things easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Adding answer to further clarify, use like this:

```
%group iOS8
   %hook IOS8_SPECIFIC_CLASS
          // your code here
   %end // end hook
%end // end group ios8

%group iOS9
   %hook IOS9_SPECIFIC_CLASS
          // your code here
   %end // end hook
%end // end group ios9


%ctor {
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 9.0) {
        %init(iOS9);
    } else {
        %init(iOS8);
    }
}
```