# Conditional call of a class inside a Hook block within THEOS/LOGOS

Tags: jailbreak, theos, logos

In my THEOS tweak, i'm hooking a class and calling one of its methods successfully.

My problem is that the method name changed following an update to the app i'm tweaking.

In the old version, the method in question takes one arguments (method:arg1) then it got updated to taking 2 args (method:arg1:arg2).
For now my code looks like this

```
%hook className

- (void)method:arg1 {
    //
}

- (void)method:arg1:arg2 {
    //
}

%end
```

This setup works fine on the new version but causes the app to crash in the old version.
Is there a way I can conditionally call one of these methods based on the bundle version ([[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"])?

I've played with #if and #endif but didn't get far.

Your help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If endif are macros compile time, not runtime like you need.

I'm learning theos logos too, but I think you should use %group and %ctor{} with a condition.

see here: [How do I use the %group feature in Theos / Logos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508442/how-do-i-use-the-group-feature-in-theos-logos)

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer.
I've actually found that answer and looked at some existing open source "tweak.mm" files to see exactly how other guys use it. but never got around to answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Cheers

```html
%group A
%hook className

- (void)method:arg1 {
    //
}

%end
%end
%group B
%hook className

- (void)method:arg1:arg2 {
    //
}

%end
%end
%ctor{
if([anObject respondsToSelctor:@selector(method:arg1:arg2)]){
%init(B)

}
else{
%init(A)
}
```